# When I'm on a call with the screen locked, I have to swipe up TWICE to get to my home screen. How to make this experience smoother?

Tags: iphone, call

There are two problems here:

When I'm on a call with the screen locked (and on speakerphone), any touch of the screen brings up the phone call, which makes it easy to hang up accidentally. How do I turn this off??

If I swipe up from this phone call lock screen, it bounces back down and then realizes it should open, but then just ends up at the normal lock screen where I need to swipe up AGAIN to get to my home screen.

What is this nonsense!? It looks and feels real buggy.

I just updated to iOS 15.5 but this has been happening for a while. Any ideas on how to fix?

It's easily & 100% reproducible for me, so you can test it yourself with a friend (or if you have 2 accounts/phone numbers of something)

Comment: I’ve noticed this…it seems like Face ID doesn’t work as well during a phone call. I wonder if they’re competing for CPU.